# adding referenced ObjectId to a document in studio/robo 3t

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

how to add a referenced document within a GUI so if I double click the Id, so that it takes me to the document directly.

```
{ 
    "employee_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0c3"), 
    "dept_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ae"), 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5411be6cd7524f36a7933f")
}
```

[image]

**Double click on the field here.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by takes me directly to document ? You wanted to click on referenced_id and go directly to that specific document ??

Comment: yes, and for some reason it's not happening, am I missing something? the ids are supposed to be global right?

Comment: not sure on that whether Gui is that powerful enough to do what you're looking for, I use robo3T/Compass I've not found anything like that yet. Maybe Studio3T has something different !!

Comment: ok, trying robo3T, otherwise you confirm that I entered the data and ids correctly?

Comment: no difference, double click has no effect. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk3VA.png

Comment: I didn't mean it would work with Robo3T, I think I said I've not found something what you're looking for, sorry if I my statements are confusing !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studio 3T currently doesn't offer this feature, but we're always open to suggestions and ideas for future updates.

We recommend you share any thoughts with us in this link: https://3t-io.uservoice.com/forums/265122-share-your-ideas-with-us

Thanks for taking the time to mention this and we hope you continue to enjoy using Studio 3T.